# Wordpress - WP_Query Multiple OrderBy Meta_Key

Tags: arguments, sql-order-by, wordpress, meta-key

I want to output a list of guides, where each guide has votes and rating. So I want to sort the guide list by rating and votes.

Example:

```
Guide Name      Rating    Votes
Guide1            10        3
Guide2            10        2
Guide3            10        1
Guide4            9         6
Guide5            9         2
```

So I have to order the guides by 2 meta_key with are

```
omvp_vote_rating and omvp_total_vote
```

I have tried many many ways to get it work, but haven't got it yet. There is one way I almost have it working, but the problem is that I can't get it to order by meta_key, I can only order it by normal field like `comment_count, modified, date, rand (random), title ...`
So here is my code

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'guides',
        'meta_key' => 'omvp_vote_rating',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'omvp_vote_rating',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'omvp_total_vote',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => 0
            ),
        ),
        'orderby'    => array(
            'title' => 'ASC', //<- This is working
            'omvp_total_vote' => 'DESC' //<- This is not working
        ),
    );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by custom select query instead.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS rating ON(
$wpdb->posts.ID = rating.post_id
AND rating.meta_key = 'omvp_vote_rating'
)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS vote ON(
$wpdb->posts.ID = vote.post_id
AND vote.meta_key = 'omvp_total_vote'
)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 3

AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY rating.meta_value, vote.meta_value ASC LIMIT 0,20"

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, object);
```

Comment: Hey, I managed to make it work with query like that. The problem is that user may chose another orderby, example orderby Title. In my code, when a user Orderby Title, ip use the normal WP_Query($args) with 'orderby' => 'title'. My problem is when a user decide to orderby title, or orderby rating, then my loop composition is changing, so it goes from "if ($posts->have_posts()) : while (..." to "if ($pageposts): global $post; foreach ($pageposts...", I am not really sure how I could handle that.

Comment: If I understood your problem correct, you can put if-else condition based on the orderby fields.

Comment: Yeah I understand correctly, but the thing is that I have to duplicate this query multiple time so it fits every need from the sent dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

Try this:

```
'order'     => 'DESC',
'orderby'   => 'omvp_vote_rating omvp_total_vote'
```

This will sort all *guides* in descending order based on *omvp_vote_rating* and *omvp_total_vote*.

For more reference, see `order` and `orderby` parameters from [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I tried it and the orderby dosen't seem to work. The list is unordered when I try this method.